# Is there anything in the question to warrant a negative vote

Tags: discussion

I had put a [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4798/how-does-apexdetail-work-can-we-show-layout-for-a-new-record)  and that question was voted down. worse the answer was also voted down. There was no comment on why it was voted down. If there was a reason for the -ve vote could anyone let me know so that i dont repeat it.

Priyanka tried to answer this question and she was also downvoted. Is it that somebody playing pranks?

Answer (score 1):

I just reviewed your question and its answer and can give you my thoughts on it:

- Your question is confusing; you ask about using apex:detail to get a standard layout and later switch the question to asking about layouts for new records yet the question title is asking how a VF tag works. If your question is not clear it is likely to get down-voted, which is what happened.
- I'm not sure why Priyanka's answer was voted down; it seems to be a pretty straight-forward answer with clear instructions. My best guess is that somebody didn't think it answered your question, but that could be because your question is not clear.

Comment: I would tend to agree with you on the question. There was surely an element of confusion in there. But what put me off was downvote for the answer